# Why i am getting Error in matlab fmincon function?

Tags: matlab, optimization, toolbox

I am not good at Matlab at all. I am trying to find minimum of function witjh constrains.

I am trying to use eample line by line as it is in documentation (https://www.mathworks.com/help/optim/ug/optimization-toolbox-tutorial.html - part Constrained Optimization Example: User-Supplied Gradients)

I have tried following code:

```
f = @(x,y) x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2)+(x.^2+y.^2)/20;
g = @(x,y) x.*y/2+(x-2).^2+(y-2).^2/2-4;

x0 = [2 ,0];
options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point','Display','iter');
gfun = @(x,y) deal(g(x,y),[]);
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(f,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],gfun,options);
```

And this is the console output:

```
>> Untitled4
Not enough input arguments.

Error in Untitled4>@(x,y)x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2)+(x.^2+y.^2)/20 (line 1)
f = @(x,y) x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2)+(x.^2+y.^2)/20;

Error in fmincon (line 552)
      initVals.f = feval(funfcn{3},X,varargin{:});

Error in Untitled4 (line 7)
[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(f,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],gfun,options);

Caused by:
    Failure in initial objective function evaluation. FMINCON cannot continue.
```

I don't understand - what is wrong with my function?

Answer (score 0):

you missed the part in the documentation defining `fun`,
and you miss-defined `gfun`.
(it is important that both are functions of a single variable, x)

Here is working code:

```
f = @(x,y) x.*exp(-x.^2-y.^2)+(x.^2+y.^2)/20;
g = @(x,y) x.*y/2+(x-2).^2+(y-2).^2/2-4;

x0 = [2 0];

options = optimoptions('fmincon','Algorithm','interior-point','Display','iter');

fun = @(x) f(x(1),x(2));
gfun = @(x) deal(g(x(1),x(2)),[]); 

[x,fval,exitflag,output] = fmincon(fun,x0,[],[],[],[],[],[],gfun,options);
```